# "in a word" vs "in a sentence"

Tags: phrases, differences, idioms, expressions

> 1. In a word, you are wrong!
> 2. In a sentence, you are wrong!

Which is more natural?

I feel "in a word" is more common than "in a sentence", but "you are wrong!" consists of three words rather than "a word"; so it seems "in a sentence" is more correct.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In a word* is an **idiom**. It means, roughly, "As a short, pithy, description, I will say...". Idioms are not expected to be literal, especially since most of them are [metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

*In a sentence*, however, is just an ordinary prepositional phrase, is **not** an idiom, and has no special or metaphorical meaning, and thus must be interpreted literally. So it has no particular reason to appear in this sentence, since *You are wrong!* -- like practically every other utterance -- is already, and obviously, *in a sentence*. In a sentence, what else is new?

Comment: Yes - one is reminded of the recurring 'Police Squad' scenes where Frank Drebin eventually bows to the inevitable and goes to ask shoe-shine Johnny what _the word on the street_ is. For the usual fee, Drebin is usually told motive, means, method, where to apprehend the criminal, how to play it ... by Johnny (the World's **other** _consulting detective_?)

Answer (score 1):

In a word, neither!

But really, I've never seen the latter used. The former is used sometimes, but it seems for your purposes "In short, you are wrong!" is a good substitution.

Comment: So you mean there should follow only one word after "in a word", right?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, neither are used by native speakers of English, as far as I know.
Plus, we would soften the statement by saying, "Actually, I think perhaps you are wrong." or
"The truth is, I'm afraid you are wrong."